# event aggregator in MVVM

Tags: events, mvvm, eventaggregator

I'm working for a while with silverlight and MVVM (in its simplest form, it's to say hand-made), but I barely understand what is an event aggregator (and how to make an implementation of this).

What is hidding behind this name? 
Can someone explain this quickly (or post a link?).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An event aggregator is generally a broker object that you can take a reference to and specify what type of events you want to receive, without having to take a reference or even be aware of the objects *generating* the events.

Prism's EventAggregator is the most common one. See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649187.aspx

It describes itself as:

> The EventAggregator service is
>   primarily a container for events that
>   allow decoupling of publishers and
>   subscribers so they can evolve
>   independently. This decoupling is
>   useful in modularized applications
>   because new modules can be added that
>   respond to events defined by the shell
>   or, more likely, other modules.

Comment: Karl Shifflett from Microsoft's patterns and practices team also has a pretty good [video on Prism's Event Aggregator](http://www.vimeo.com/11585963) explaining some of the concepts mentioned by @rrhartjr above.